# Pass javascript variable to twig form_widget FOSymfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, local-storage

I want to set the array of form_widget in twig using some localStorage variables which i have saved in javacript variables.

Which is the best way to do this?

I tried getting the ID of the input field and setting the value with jquery from js but it's not working

```
<div class="col-sm-3 year">
             {{ form_widget(form.birthdate.year, {'value': 'birthdate.year'}) }}
          </div>
```

```
<script>
   var birthdateJSON = localStorage.getItem('user_birthdate');
   var birthdate = JSON.parse(birthdateJSON);
</script>
```

Comment: You can't. Twig is executed serverside and javascript clientside. U'd need to resort to javascript to modify the form after render

Answer (score 0):

Twig rendering is done/completed (serverside) before javascript (clientside) is ready to be used. So you can not go back in time. Only option is to use javascript.

If your form_widget returns a select box: (I assume it is since you speak of "the array")

```
<div class="year">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    var birthdateJSON = localStorage.getItem('user_birthdate');
    var birthdate = JSON.parse(birthdateJSON);
    var year = birthdate.year;

    // Be sure to pre-select it after document ready
    $(function() {
        // You can do this
        $('.year select option[value="' + year + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        // Or this
        $('.year select').val(year);
    });
</script>
```

If it is a textfield

```
<div class="year">
    <input type="text" name="myselect" id="myselect">
</div>

<script>
    var birthdateJSON = localStorage.getItem('user_birthdate');
    var birthdate = JSON.parse(birthdateJSON);
    var year = birthdate.year;

    // Be sure to pre-fill it after document ready
    $(function() {
        // You can do this
        $('.year input').val(year);
    });
</script>
```